# Showing that $x=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}1/n_k$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I have to prove the following : For all $x\in \mathbb{R} $  with $0<x<1$ there is a sequence of natural numbers  $1<n_1<n_2<... $  , such that $$x= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n_k}$$

My idea is to use that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ . If $(n_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of natural numbers  , then the sum is in $\mathbb{Q}$ . Now for each $x \in \mathbb{R}$ there exists a sequence   $(n_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}  \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $$|x-\sum_{k=1}^{m}1/n_k|<\epsilon $$ for all $\epsilon>0$ and $n\geq m$ .

Comment: That's what you are required to prove. And where is the fact that $\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R$ used here?

Comment: I thought the last inequality holds because of this fact .

Comment: Note that fractions $\dfrac{1}{p}$ do not cover all rationals. And also not that $n_k$ must be strictly increasing.

Comment: That is related to [Engel's expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engel_expansion) which exists for any real.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. Let $n_1$ be an integer in $(1/x,2/x)$ (note that size of the interval is $1/x>1$) and for $k\geq 2$ let
$$n_{k}=\left\lfloor \frac{1}{x-\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}\frac{1}{n_j}}\right\rfloor+1.$$
Show that $(n_k)_k$ is strictly increasing and for $k\geq 1$
$$\frac{1}{n_k}<x-\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}\frac{1}{n_j}<\frac{2}{n_k}.$$
which implies that $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}1/n_j=x$.

Comment: Thanks for your help . Well , then $n_k$ is monotonically increasing . Should I then consider $k \rightarrow \infty$ ?

Comment: @AnabolicHorse I edited my answer. Is it better now?

Comment: Yes , thank you for your help .

Answer (score 1):

Won't **binary expansion** be the simplest answer?

Comment: OP needs a sequence with infinite terms $n_k$. Finite binary expansions should be extended. For instance $1/2=1/4+1/8+1/16+\dots$.

Comment: Actually, yes, it does work, as $x\in(0,1)$. The question also works for $x>1$, and then binary expansion won't work, but for $0<x<1$, no problem. There is just a trick for real numbers that have a finite binary expansion.